# Flutter: Cannot pass a boolean type parameter through GoRouter

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I want to pass a bool type parameter through GoRouter but I get this message error:

> The argument type String cannot be assigned to the parameter type "bool"

But I can't really figure out where this error comes from.
Is `String` the only allowed type in queryParams ?

Here's my code:

`main.dart`

```
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(routes: [
    GoRoute(name: 'home', path: '/home', builder: ((context, state) => Home(
                location: state.queryParams['location']!,
                time: state.queryParams['time']!,
                flag: state.queryParams['flag']!,
                isDaytime: state.queryParams['isDaytime']!,
            )   
        )   
    ),  
]);
```

`world_time.dart`

```
class WorldTime {

  String _url = 'https://api-urlxxxxxxx';
  String location;
  String flag;
  String time = ''; 
  bool isDaytime = true;

  WorldTime({ required this.location, required this.flag }); 

  ...
}
```

`home.dart`

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
    String location;
    String time;
    String flag;
    State isDaytime;

    Home({
        Key? key,
        required this.location,
        required this.time,
        required this.flag,
        required this.isDaytime,
    }) : super(key: key);

    @override
    // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
    _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}
```

`loading.dart`

```
class Loading extends StatefulWidget {
    const Loading({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    _LoadingState createState() => _LoadingState();
}


class _LoadingState extends State<Loading> {

    void setupWorldTime() async {
        WorldTime instance = WorldTime(location: 'London', flag: 'england.png');
        await instance.getTime();

        ...

        context.goNamed('home', queryParams: {
                'location': instance.location,
                'time': instance.time,
                'flag': instance.flag,
                'isDaytime': instance.isDaytime,
         }); 
     }
}
```

Comment: What is `State isDaytime;` in `home.dart`? Shouldn't it be `bool isDayTime`?

Comment: @PeterKoltai I tried bool isDayTime but I get the same error message.

Comment: If I remember correctly with `queryParams` you are restricted to string values. You can either pass `true` / `false` or `1` / `0` as string and convert it, or you can use the `state.extra` configuration to pass an object that can contain types members.